# Magento 1.9 - How to Filter and Aggregate Order API Response

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, search, rest-api

I need to Filter and Aggregate the query of **(/Orders)** endpoint in Magento 1.9

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

and what are the **Aggregate** and **Filter** parameters

Thank you.